# Intent is depreciated, What is the alternative?

Tags: android, android-intent, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I am new android developer and I am building a App in SDK 28 with minSdkVersion 22.

Using a codefragment from another App I now get the warning message:
*'android.content.intent' is deprecated.*

I found some threads regarding the usage of *getIntent()* but I am creating a new intent in my case in a RecyclerViewAdapter to open a new Activity.

You can check out my Code or Screenshot below:

```
package com.example.chris.projectartifact.bb_Items;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.chris.projectartifact.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemRViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Items> mData;

    public ItemRViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Items> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }


    @Override
    public ItemRViewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext); //TODO what does that?
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_cardview_cards,parent,false);
        return new ItemRViewAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRViewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.ivSpell_img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getItemImage());
        holder.tvSpell_title.setText(mData.get(position).getItemTitle());

        holder.cardView_spells_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // This is where my problem is..!
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, itemClickable.class);     
                intent.putExtra("itemName", mData.get(position).getItemTitle());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvSpell_title;
        CardView cardView_spells_id;
        ImageView ivSpell_img;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvSpell_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSpell_title);
            ivSpell_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSpell_img);

            cardView_spells_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView_spells_id);
        }
    }

}
```

Screenshot:
[image: intent is strikethrough]

Maybe you can help me with that!

Edit new Screenshot where I fixed the itemClickable not recognized Issue.
[image: Fixed itemClickable.class]

Thanks!
CG

Comment: In documentation, I can't find anywhere saying intent as deprecated

Comment: hey @VivekMishra. Thanks for checking the Documentation.

Do you have any idea where this could come from then?

I copied this class from a sdk 26 programme into a sdk 28 programme. Could this make an issue?

Comment: may be  this is because it cannot find itemClickable.class

Comment: Check your imports too.

Comment: No, it is not because of itemClickable. Changed that obviously. 

import com.example.chris.projectartifact.R;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



import java.util.List;


That are my imports. I dont know how to edit them properly, though :s

Comment: Could you try placing your cursor on the striked-out "Intent" text, and pressing Ctrl+F1 to see more details? That message is usually helpful.

Comment: @TheGamer007 did that :)

Comment: This is unusual. What kind of class is `itemClickable`? And have you tried to "Invalidate caches / Restart" from the File menu? This seems like a false positive, so maybe that would fix it.

Comment: @TheGamer007 I tried this aswell and sadly that did not help. itemClickable is Activity, therefore I would say a basic java class (?, not sure what it should be else). And the warning is happening in the Adapter of my RecyclerView. It works as expected by the way, but the issue is still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)) is not deprecated the problem is with your `itemClickable.class` because it is not recognized.

Either you have somehow enabled extra warnings that identify Intent as deprecated or something is really stack at your machine.

[image]

Comment: Sorry Sir. This is not the issue. To let me believe you I will add a new screenshot where I erased that issue.

Comment: Added a screenshot of my Android Studio 3.2.1. I would suggest a restart (Android Studio/PC), project cleanup, reset of Android Studio to default settings!

Comment: Hey. I did that but it did not change the outcome. Can you imagine that it has something to do with me using a RecyclerView.Adapter<myRViewAdapater.ViewHolder > as an extension?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of just using `intent`:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        intent = intent // Yeah, just use `intent` XD

        setContent {
```

no need for `getIntent()` anymore